# Remove String in Limit Maximum

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a string that has `14 characters` `TEST,TEST,TEST`

the problem is I want to limit the string becomes 7 characters and store to DB

** I have tried this code:**

```
$text = "TEST,TEST,TEST";
DB::table('table')
       ->update([
       'name' => substr($text, 0, 7);
    ]);
```

but the result like this `TEST,TE`, I don't want to show last cut character, I want to the result like this `TES` if not up to 7 characters.

I want to limit every string that insert to database just 7 characters, if from 7 characters there are words that are truncated like 'TE', 'T', 'TES' I don't want to display it, so only the full words are displayed that is 'TEST'.

Comment: What if you try this `'name' => substr($text, 0,3);`

Comment: you mean  6 char + ','  = 7 char?

Comment: You want to limit your string to 6 characters but are expecting "TES" as output? Am I missing something? Can you explain a little more?

Comment: sorry i have edited my question

Comment: which character `I don't want to show last cut character`

Comment: Still don't understand, cutting `TEST,TEST,TEST` to 7 chars you get exactly `TEST,TE`. If you want `TES`, why don't you cut to 3 characters?

Comment: but you said your string is 14 character `if not up to 7 characters`

Comment: i want to  show full character like this 'TEST' not cut character like 'TE', 'T', 'TES'

Comment: you use `substr($text, 0, 7)` so its given result like cut character like above

Comment: I think he means he doesn't want partial words.

Comment: i have edited my question in order to you all understand, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this at `PHP` side and then use it in `UPDATE` query.

```
$text = "TEST,TEST,TEST";

$exp = explode(",", $text); // Create an array

$final_string = '';

foreach($exp as $v)
{
    //Check when new value is added and string length is less than 7, concat it
    if(strlen($final_string) + strlen($v) <= 7)
    {
        $final_string .= "$v,";
    }
}

$final_string = trim($final_string, ",");

echo $final_string; // OUTPUT: TEST
```

It will work for dynamic strings too. For e.g. your string is `T,TEST,TEST` it will return `T,TEST`.

> Please note this solution will work if you have comma separated values.

To make it work with spaces, comma and other characters, replace `explode` with `preg_split` as follows,

```
$exp = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $text);
```

Comment: What if it's a space delimited list of words.

Comment: OP hasn't specified about spaces. Seems its a comma separated string only. Have added a note in my answer that it will work if you need it for comma separated strings.

Comment: Updated my answer to make it work with spaces and any other character desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one delimiter you can use `explode`:

```
$text = 'TEST,TEST,TEST';
$word = explode(',', substr($text, 0, 7))[0];
```

If you need multiple delimiters you can use `preg_split` and add your delimiters in the regular expression, space and comma in this example:

```
$text = "TEST,TEST,TEST";
$word = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", substr($text, 0, 7))[0];
```